# ffmpeg creating mp4 vs mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I have two mp4 files. One of them was given to me and plays well under mediawiki (using the MediawikiPlayer extension). The other I created from a WMV file and it does not play. When I look at the two files through the eyes of ffprobe, they appear to be very different. The working file returns this:

```
Metadata:
  major_brand     : mp42
  minor_version   : 0
  compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
  creation_time   : 2013-12-28 20:25:51
  encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.9 2013052900
Duration: 00:00:17.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 957 kb/s
  Chapter #0:0: start -0.066733, end 17.017000
  Metadata:
    title           : Chapter 1
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 704x480 [SAR 10:11 DAR 4:3], 824 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2013-12-28 20:25:51
    encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2013-12-28 20:25:51
  Stream #0:2(und): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574), 0 kb/s
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2013-12-28 20:25:51
```

The non-working produces this:

```
Metadata:
  major_brand     : isom
  minor_version   : 512
  compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
  encoder         : Lavf55.0.100
Duration: 00:05:25.79, start: 0.033333, bitrate: 1331 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 704x528 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1198 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

What ffmpeg options do I need to supply to convert my wmv file to an mp4 file like the first of those listed here (the working one)?

Update: 2015-10-23, here is the full output from ffmpeg for the non-working file:

```
E:\>ffmpeg -i non-working.mp4
ffmpeg version N-71329-g235589e Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libblu
ray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena
ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 22.101 / 54. 22.101
  libavcodec     56. 34.100 / 56. 34.100
  libavformat    56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 13.101 /  5. 13.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'non-working.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.0.100
  Duration: 00:10:12.94, start: 0.033333, bitrate: 1324 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 704x528 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1191 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: You have to show your `ffmpeg` command and the **complete** console output. It will have the info necessary for an answer. I have an idea of what the issue may be, but without additional info I won't make an uneducated guess.

Comment: The problem is the file that works was not produced by me, so I don't have the ffmpeg command or output. I don't remember what I used for my file, but that file doesn't work, so it's not going to be all that helpful, I'd think.

Comment: Then at least show the complete console output of: `ffmpeg -i nonworking.mp4`.

Comment: The output is posted above, except the information on the ffmpeg version.

Comment: ffmpeg version N-71329-g235589e Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)

Comment: There is more missing than just the version. Please add the info to the question instead of attempting to cram it all into a comment.

Comment: I found a tool, the Miro Video Converter (http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) that produces mp4 files that work, so there is no longer any urgency. Also, I believe at least a big part of the issue has to do with 'MPEG-4 Part 2' ('Simple Profile') and 'MPEG-4 Part 10' (H.264/AVC). So, perhaps the question I want to ask is: How to I use ffmpeg to produce an h.264/avc mp4 file? The answer to that seems to be here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Comment: Once again, the missing console output info will provide the details necessary to provide the answer.

Comment: I have added the full console output to my initial post above.